# Cant sum a formula in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a formula

```
If {@total} = 0 then 0 
Else ({@countrow} / {@total}) 
 * 100
```

Countrow formula:

```
Count({@rowOccupied}, 
  {table.column1})
```

Total formula:

```
  Count({@table.column2}, 
  {table.column1})
```

Percentage is working fine but i want to calculate the average of percentage.
When when i try to sum this formula it says this field cannot be summarised.

I am calculating percentage per group and i want an average of percentage per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal can't ***total totals***. So a formula that involves any type of aggregation cannot be totaled.

One option is to compute the ratio of the grand sums to give you a true average ratio. Averaging ratios, as you intended to do can cause the result to be biased because small group ratios count just as much as larger group ratios.

If you truly want the average of the group ratios then at least one Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library) provides functions that allow you to ***total totals*** in Crystal. Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Alternatively, use a View/SP/Command to pre-calculate the group ratios in the data source for the report.